# Isn't draws vertical line on hover when I move cursor fast

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I use `vue-chartJs` library, when I move cursor fast vertical line on hover not showing, but when I move cursor slowly - it's work perfect. Can you help me with this problem

```
onHover: function () {
    if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
        var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
        ctx = this.chart.ctx,
        x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
        topY = this.chart.scales["y-axis-0"].top,
        bottomY = this.chart.scales["y-axis-0"].bottom;

        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
        ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.setLineDash([3, 3]);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#45171d";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a guess, but since the function is called 'onHover' I guess it only runs if the cursor stops long enough for the hover to activate. Hover is often used to display tooltips. In the case of a chart this is often used to show more detail (exact figures) when resting your cursor on a certain part of the chart. If you want the cursor to permanently display the detail, maybe you can bind it to another event such as mouse move.

Answer (score 0):

Solved
I override config.hover.animationDuration pro